# Using custom views with restful api in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have created a custom view to get the user who rated by their customers but they have not yet rated their customers. Now the problem is that I don't know how to call this view in the rating restful api controller?

[image: File structure screenshot]

Comment: You don't use views with restful api controllers!

Comment: REST is about either returning XML or JSON from the controller only return ['models' => $model];